# Page not found 404 with Django

Tags: python, django

I don't understand where is situated my problem. I get an urls' problem but I don't see where I made a mistake.

I have a project : `Etat_civil`

I have an app : `BirthCertificate`

My `views.py app` is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from BirthCertificate.forms import BirthCertificateForm

# Create your views here.

def BirthCertificateAccueil(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer la page d'accueil de la rubrique Acte de Naissance 

    #Cherche le fichier html accueil et le renvois
    template = loader.get_template('accueil.html') 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))


def BirthCertificateCreationAccueil(request) :
     # Fonction permettant de créer la page de création du formulaire de la partie : Acte de Naissance 

     template = loader.get_template('creation_accueil.html')
     return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

def BirthCertificateForm(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            numero_acte = form.cleaned_data["Numero de l'acte"]
            nom = form.cleaned_data['Nom']
            prenom = form.cleaned_data['Prenom']

    else :
        form = BirthCertificateForm()

    template = loader.get_template('birthform.html')

    return render(request, template.render(request),locals())
```

I have also a `urls.py app` :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil$', views.BirthCertificateAccueil),
    url(r'^creation$', views.BirthCertificateCreationAccueil),
    url(r'^formulaire$', views.BirthCertificateForm),
]
```

And my `urls.py project` looks like :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from BirthCertificate import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^BirthCertificate/', include('BirthCertificate.urls')),
]
```

The birthform.html file looks like :

```
{% if envoi %} Votre formulaire est bien complété ! {% endif %}

<form action="{% url "BirthCertificate.views.BirthCertificateForm" %}" method="post">{% 
csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_table }}
<input type ="submit" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

When I launch : http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/formulaire

I get this error :

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/formulaire Using the
>   URLconf defined in Etat_civil.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,
>   in this order:
>
> ^admin/
>
> ^BirthCertificate/ ^accueil$
>
> ^BirthCertificate/^creation$
>
> The current URL, BirthCertificate/formulaire, didn't match
>   any of these. You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True
>   in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will
>   display a standard 404 page.

Im stuck with Django and I would like to know if you see the error ?

Thank you !

#

**EDIT :**

I had a mistake in my `forms.py` : I wrote `max_lenght` instead of `max_length`.
But I get always an error :

```
TypeError at /BirthCertificate/formulaire
BirthCertificateForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/formulaire
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
BirthCertificateForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
Exception Location: /Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Etat_civil/BirthCertificate/views.py in BirthCertificateForm, line 34
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Etat_civil',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 20 Nov 2016 16:16:16 +0000
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yep, I killed the port, make a runserver again and always this error. However, /accueil and /creation woks fine so I don't understand.

Comment: try to rename your view `BirthCertificateForm` to `BirthCertificateView`, not sure but may be there is some names conflict

Comment: @devxplorer I tried but none effect. Always the same error. What is strange for me it's that works for /accueil and /creation but not to /formulaire.

Comment: You have no url matching this:http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/formulaire

Comment: @joelgoldstick I don't understand your answer, I have a problem with my url but this url looks like to the others. http://localhost:8000/BirtCertificate/accueil and http://localhost:8000/BirtCertificate/creation works but not http://localhost:8000/BirtCertificate/formulaire. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function render() takes template_name as argument.
Try to change return in Birth CertificateForm() to this:

```
return render(request, 'birthform.html', locals())
```

EDIT:

Probably you have problem in this line of code:

```
form = BirthCertificateForm()
```

I suggest you yo change view and to use following pattern:

```
form = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    numero_acte = form.cleaned_data["Numero de l'acte"]
    nom = form.cleaned_data['Nom']
    prenom = form.cleaned_data['Prenom']
```

and now you dont need this if-else validation:

```
if request.method == 'POST' :
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't understand, always the same thing, error 404

Comment: @Andromedae93 this line 'return render(request, template.render(request),locals())' contains error, try to change it to 'return render(request, 'birthform.html', locals())'. Hope this will help.

Comment: What I did ;) But the error 404 is still there. I added the birthform.html, maybe the error comes from this file ?

Comment: @Andromedae93 hmm, does http://localhost:8000/BirthCertificate/accueil opens correctly? If yes then just for check please comment all urls in app urls.py file and try to open it again. Is it possible that urls is loading from another  urls file without formulaire pattern in it.

Comment: Yes /accueil and /creation works fine. Ok I will try

Comment: I edited my post. I had an error in my forms.py, but still an error. Du to the argument in form = BirthCertificateForm()

Comment: @Andromedae93 try: 
        form = BirthCertificateForm(None) instead of form = BirthCertificateForm()

Comment: Nop : Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'. Sorry as I said, I begin with Django :/

Comment: @Andromedae93 I updated my answer, try. If this will not help show your form.py

Comment: It's strange because I followed a form tutorial. After your modification : `Error during template rendering

In template `/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Etat_civil/BirthCertificate/templates/birthform.html, error at line 3.
`Reverse for 'BirthCertificate.views.BirthCertificateForm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: @Andromedae93 Modify birthform.html <form action="{% url "BirthCertificate.views.BirthCertificateForm" %}" change to <form action="". Btw: very interesting tutorial :)

Comment: I just get the submit button in my page, it's normal ? I don't understand why I don't have fields like : nom, prenom, ...

Comment: @Andromedae93 first try following: return render(request, template.render(request),locals()) change to return render(request, template.render(request),{'form': form}). This will pass context varible form to your template and form should to become visible. If this will not help then try to rename BirthCertificateForm in views.py to BirthCertificateView. And change urls.py url(r'^formulaire$', views.BirthCertificateForm), to url(r'^formulaire$', views.BirthCertificateView),

Comment: I will look my script, because I get again some problems. Thank you for your help !